# NSDictionary setValue:

Tags: objective-c, debugging, key-value-observing, nsmutabledictionary, key-value-coding

OK, this is driving me nuts -- please tell me I'm not losing my mind!

I declare:

```
NSMutableDictionary* generalSettingsDict;
```

im my .h

I init:

```
generalSettingsDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
```

in a viewWillAppear

I set:

```
[generalSettingsDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:control.on]
                       forkey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:control.tag]];
```

in a method:

```
-(void)settingChanged:(UISwitch*)control forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

And I get **"NSMutableDictionary may not respond to setValue:forkey:"** and the app crashes when it is run.

Please help :(

Comment: You also have a typo: forKey:, not forkey:. And for the record, `NSMutableDictionary` does support `setValue:forKey:`, but I still prefer to use `setObject:forKey:`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A) `forkey:` should be `forKey:`. Capitalization is important.

B) `setValue:forKey:` is a KVC method. It may work as you expect here, but the proper method to use for NSMutableDictionary is `setObject:forKey:`

Comment: You'll also find, even after correcting the method name, that KVC keys must be strings. You have to use the native NSMutableDictionary `setObject:forKey:` method to use arbitrary objects as keys.

Answer (score 6):

You want `setObject:forKey:`. `setValue:forKey:` is part of the key-value coding protocol. `NSMutableDictionary` provides `setObject:forKey:`.